# How to tell if lazy loading is working?

Tags: lazy-loading

Im using a js called blazy and the image loads as i scroll down the page to it.
The image shows up in pingdom speed test, should it show up in the speed test tree if lazy loading is working for the image?

Comment: F12 browser tools, look at the network inspector and you can see exactly what gets loaded when.

Comment: Maybe it check the user-agent header to see what "browser" it's interacting with?

Comment: @AlexK. i did that and went to network tab. The image isnt showing, does that mean its working?

Comment: One would expect them to show up as you scroll

Comment: I mean its not in the list of things loaded under network tab

Answer (score 6):

### Very easy solution:

in Google Chrome open chrome **dev tools**.

**1. Select the Network tab**

[step one screenshot/image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkMHs.png)

**2. Click on `No throttling`**

[step two screenshot/image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxtF.png)

**3. And then choose how much you want to make the network slower to let Lazy Loading show up (until the data is received)**

You can check this way if your app/site lazy loading is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I've seen using the correct Lazy Router Setup will result in Angular serving back a minified js file bundle, which has the same name of your lazy router @NgModule ts custom file..

That's what Lazy loading is all about anyway.. bundling resources upon request..

I've added a simple Lazy Loading ts file and called it lazy-loading-router, and looking in the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools.. I can see a minified js file called lazy-loading-router.js

[image]

> STEP 1: Create a custom declarations NgModule file : lazy-loading-router.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Comp2Component } from './components/comp2/comp2/comp2.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        Comp2Component
    ],
    imports: [
        Comp2Component,
        RouterModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ]
  })
  export class lazyMod {}
```

> STEP 2: Create lazyloader.ts Router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

const com2Lazy: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'comp2', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-loading-router').then(e => e.lazyMod) 
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(com2Lazy, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class lazyLoader {}
```

> STEP 3 Add lazyLoader to your App.module.ts